# The definition of 1-quotient map in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

Just a quick question, i want to know the definition of 1-quotient map. I meet it in the textbook but i don't know the definition.

Comment: What textbook is this? "1-quotient map" is a term I've never heard of in a functional-analytic context, and one whose only actual appearance on google appears to be this very question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We recall from Functional Analysis that a $1$-quotient map is a contractive linear
>   $T : E \to  F$ between normed spaces which takes the open unit ball of $E$ onto the
>   open unit ball of $F$. These are exactly the maps whose canonically associated map $E/\mathrm{Ker}\,(T) \to  F$ is an isometric isomorphism. (Note that this is implied by, but is not the same as, that $T$ takes the closed unit ball of $E$ onto the closed
>   unit ball of $F$.) Indeed if $F$ is a closed linear subspace of $E$, then the canonical
>   map $E \to  E/F$ is a $1$-quotient map.

Source: [Page 21 here](http://www.math.uh.edu/~dblecher/op.pdf)